# Jax-Rs and JSP sessions

Tags: java, rest, jsp, session, servlets

I'm working on a project's security schema, build on Embedded Tomcat,using JaX-RS. I have secured the server side,and I need every time an unauthorized user tries to access a specific JSP page, to be redirected to the login page. The problem is that rest services and jsp create different sessions, therefore required session objects return null in jsp

Code Examples:

VisorSecurity Class

```
public class VisorSecurity
{
   private String userName;
   private String role;
   private boolean isAuth;

   public VisorSecurity(){

   }

   public String getUserName()
   {
      return userName;
   }

   public void setUserName(String userName)
   {
      this.userName = userName;
   }

   public String getRole()
   {
      return role;
   }

   public void setRole(String role)
   {
      this.role = role;
   }

   public boolean isIsAuth()
   {
      return isAuth;
   }

   public void setIsAuth(boolean isAuth)
   {
      this.isAuth = isAuth;
   }


}
```

A Rest function

```
 @GET
   @Path("/select/")
   public String selectServer(@Context HttpServletRequest req)
   {
      HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
      VisorSecurity security = isAuthorized(session);
      if (security.isIsAuth()) {
         StringBuilder serverList = new StringBuilder();
         List<Server> servers = Ebean.find(Server.class).findList();
         serverList.append("<ul class=\"nav nav-pills nav-stacked\">");
         for (Server server : servers) {
            String this_link = "<li role=\"presentation\"><a href=\"/View/serverControl.jsp?server=" + server.getName() + "\">" + server.getName() + " Control</a></li>";
            serverList.append(this_link);
         }
         serverList.append("</ul>");
         System.out.println(serverList.toString());
         return serverList.toString();
      }
      else {
         return "unauthorized";
      }
   }
```

Authorization.class

```
public VisorSecurity isAuthorized(HttpSession session)
   {
      VisorSecurity security;

      try {
         security = (VisorSecurity)session.getAttribute("security");
          System.out.println("Into Login: " + session.getId());
         _logger.info("User: \n");
         _logger.info(security.getUserName() + "\n");
         _logger.info(security.getRole());
      }
      catch (Exception e) {

         security = new VisorSecurity();
         security.setUserName("none");
         security.setRole("unauthorized");
         _logger.info("User: \n");
         _logger.info(security.getUserName() + "\n");
         _logger.info(security.getRole());
         security.setIsAuth(false);
      }

      return security;
   }
```

navigator jsp

```
 <% //Want to retrieve the session
         session.getAttribute("security"); %>
```

I tried everything related posts suggesting, but always the jsp creates a new session

Comment: Sessions in REST? The "S" in "REST" stands for Stateless, not for Stateful. There's a major fundamental misunderstanding here. You've been blinded by the REST overhype. As a MVC controller, you should be using a servlet instead of a webservice. Webservices are intented to be stateless and request based. E.g. to provide a list of results in JSON/XML/CSV format based on a specific query (which the client then shows in e.g. a dropdown after an ajax call).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and notes! Well I only need a small scriplet in JSP in order to check if a user is authorized. I also tried to create a session in servlets, but still had different ID from the session in JSP.